# Passing PyQt QLineEdit text as parameter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to edit a QLineEdit widget and then send the new text as a parameter to a function, but it's always returning the original text instead of the new text. Here's a snippet of the code

```
self.shortCoffee1Label = QLineEdit("0")
self.shortCoffee1Label.editingFinished.connect(self.sendValue(48, int(self.shortCoffee1Label.text())))
```

and then the sendValue function

```
    def sendValue(self, var, val):
        def emmitValue():
            self.messageReceived.setText("Sending new value...")
            print("var received: " + str(var))
            print("val received: " + str(val))
            self.thread.sendValue(var, val)
        return emmitValue
```

But val is always 0, which is the original value it was set to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Basically what the individual using the unnecessary and more complex Lambda expression is not telling you is that when using a Connect statement you do not supply it with a function call - aka `Function()` but you supply it with the function - aka `Function` then if you have parameters you wish to pass you do that within that function so we would have this `self.shortCoffee1Label.editingFinished.connect(self.SendNewValue)` then in `def SendNewValue(self):` you would have the line that calls what you want using parameters as follows:

Comment: `self.sendValue(48, int(self.shortCoffee1Label.text()))` and that is all you need within that function or there are other ways to do this that are equally less complex than adding a Lambda expression as that violates the K.I.S.S. rule of programming (Keep It Simple and Smart) by adding unnecessary complexity in order to stuff as much on one line of code as you can -- which was proven to be a bad methodology a long time ago.

Comment: But since I want to have multiple QLineEdits to throw that sendValue function, I need both parameters - var is the lineedit that sent the value and val is the value of the line edit. If I do it like you're proposing, I'll only be able to throw the value and won't know from which line edit it came from right?

Answer (score 0):

If you do like that the program will store the value "0" and attach it to editingFinished instead of refreshing it every time you call the function. So you should use lambda (sorry for my bad English):

```
self.shortCoffee1Label = QLineEdit("0")
self.shortCoffee1Label.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.sendValue(48, int(self.shortCoffee1Label.text())))
```

Comment: adding lambda makes the program not execute the function at all

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Here's the final code:

```
self.shortCoffee1Label.editingFinished.connect(self.sendValue(48, self.shortCoffee1Label))

 def sendValue(self, var, val):
        def emmitValue():
            self.messageReceived.setText("Sending new value...")
            print("var received: " + str(var))
            print("val received: " + str(int(val.text())))
            self.thread.sendValue(var, int(val.text()))
        return emmitValue
```

So the idea was to send the object itself as the parameter so I could retrieve the updated text. As it turns out, it might be interpreting that as a "send the text that this object had at compile". By sending the object itself, the problem was resolved.